# Argument of type '(_spaceService_: any) => any' is not assignable to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

hey If I update the below code in my codebase I am getting the following error, can you tell me how to fix it..providing my code and error below

```
let spaceService;
            beforeEach(inject(function(_spaceService_, ''){
                spaceService = _spaceService_
            ));

Argument of type '(_spaceService_: any) => any' is not assignable to pramter of type 'any[]'.
```

**Property 'push' is missing in type '(*spaceService*:any) => any'.**

Comment: What is the rest of the error sentence?

Comment: @ZivWeissman thanks for your reply...updated the full error

Comment: So basically you have the answer you need - spaceService is an array, so you can use spaceService.push(/_spaceService_/) or spaceService[0] = /_spaceService_/ - Why does spaceService is an array?

Comment: @ZivWeissman can you update in my code its so confusing :(

Comment: I've added it as an answer I hope it is more clear, you might need to figure out if you need array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason (maybe from a different part of your code) the variable spaceService is an array, there for you need to change your code to the following:

```
let spaceService; 
// if it is not initiated you should use:
//let spaceService: any[] = new array[];
            beforeEach(inject(function(_spaceService_, ''){
                spaceService.push(_spaceService_);
            ));
```